# Analog Comparator works on Nano, but not working on Pro Mini 3.3v

Tags: arduino-nano, atmega328, arduino-pro-mini

I've coded an analog comparator to work on Nano, but the same code does not work on a brand new Pro Mini 3.3v 8MHz. The serial monitor just outputs the triggered interrupt continuously. Lines orange and yellow have the potentiometer.

[image]

[image]

The code is:

```
#define INDICATOR_PIN 8

volatile boolean triggered;
volatile boolean rising;
volatile byte acsr_value;

ISR (ANALOG_COMP_vect) {
  if (triggered) return;           // For testing purposes, ignore the interrupt if we haven't reported the last one yet.
                                   // This also effects some crude debouncing.
  cli();
  acsr_value = ACSR;
  rising = (acsr_value & bit(ACO)) > 0;
  triggered = true;
  sei();
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin (115200);
  Serial.println ("Started.");

  pinMode(INDICATOR_PIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(INDICATOR_PIN, LOW);

  ADCSRB = ADCSRB & ! bit(ACME);   // disable Analog Comparator Multiplexer Enable
  ACSR =  bit(ACI)                 // clear Analog Comparator Interrupt Flag
        | bit(ACIE)                // set Analog Comparator Interrupt Enable
        | bit(ACIS1) | bit(ACIS0)  // select rising edge: ACIS1/ACIS0 Analog Comparator Interrupt Mode Select
        ;
}

void loop() {
  if (triggered) show_what_happened();
}

// just give an indication via Serial and LED that we handled an interrupt...
void show_what_happened() {
  digitalWrite(INDICATOR_PIN, HIGH);

  Serial.print ("Triggered! ACSR=");
  Serial.print (acsr_value, BIN);
  if (rising)
    Serial.println (" RISING EDGE (as expected)");
  else
    Serial.println (" FALLING EDGE .. wtf, didn't ask for this, but every so often one slips thru. Maybe a sync issue reading ACSR.");

  triggered = false;

  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(INDICATOR_PIN, LOW);
}
```

Why does it work well on Nano? I've read all the related sections in the datasheet and tested several ACSR configurations.

**I'm seeing the voltage levels changes on a DSO**, and it works as expected in the Nano.

I'd like to add that when loading the code to the board, it either prints nothing, or prints continuously RISING FALLING edge. Sometimes, when a connect the serial monitor, it just stops flashing the led. It is definitely an erratic behavior.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you tell us the exact board models/ microcontrollers?

Comment: Yes. It's an Arduino Pro Mini 3.3v 8Mhz board. Atmega328p.

Comment: Ok, just in case (ISR names and such). Are you using [this circuit](https://github.com/tardate/LittleArduinoProjects/tree/master/playground/AnalogComparator)? Because it sets AIN1 to a reference of 2.5V. Just thnking out loud, but internally in a 3.3v board, that might be too high.

Comment: I edited the question with the schematics. I assure you that at first, the level of AIN0 is fewer that AIN1, and then when I move the potentiometer, the level surpass AIN1, moment when I expect it to trigger the interruption, but this does not happen. I'm starting to think that there must be some kind of limitation in the Arduino Pro Mini board.

Comment: There's no limitation - the signals go straight from the header pins to the TQFP pins on both boards.  The only difference is AREF - 5V on the Nano, 3.3V on the Promini you are using. What level signal are you sending in, and comparing against?

Comment: The level signals will be the same proportion for any AREF. The relevant thing is that I move the potentiometer and AIN0 surpass AIN1, which is happening, I see it in the DSO.

Comment: No, that's not what @CrossRoads meant. AIN0 can surpass AIN1, but if the level isn't within 3.3V range, this won't work. Analog comparator works based on the AREF voltage. Nano's AREF is 5v. Pro Mini 3.3v 8Mhz 's AREF is 3.3V. So check the voltage level of AINs.

Comment: The FTDI is set to work with 3.3v and is feeding the Pro Mini with this voltage.

Comment: Do you have a proper schematic? I can't tell from the image you posted what values of resistors you used.

Comment: The circuit next to the FT232 (set to 3.3v) is a voltage devider with a 2 * 10K in series and 3 * 470K in parallel. Midpoint is the reference to D7. The variable reference is a voltage devider between a 10K and a potentiometer that goes from 23K to 150K. The schematic a posted is made with the autoroute of Fritzing, so don't take it as perfect. It's just to give the idea.

Comment: Ok, but is your Fritzing image correct? Because it looks like your voltage divider is connected to RXI !! instead of 3.3V.

Comment: If your voltage on pin D6 and D7 are really close, you will get trigger continiously. So, check the voltage on those two pins.

Comment: The delta range is: minimum 2.32v, average 2.52v and maximum is 3.12v . Please, check in your breadboard that the continuous triggering is because these 200mv downwards and 600mv upwards is not enough delta to keep comparator at ease. I mean, "really close" is not specified in the 328 datasheet, at least, I didn't find it.